# Mocking ColumnDefinitions.Definition does return mock, but is behaves like null in the tested code

Tags: java, unit-testing, cassandra, mocking, mockito

I have following code preparing mocks to test my service using Cassandra (I need to mock `com.datastax.driver.core.ColumnDefinitions.Definition`) :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestMyClass{
private MyClass target;
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    ColumnDefinitions mockColumnDefinitions=Mockito.mock(ColumnDefinitions.class);
    Mockito.when(mockRow.getColumnDefinitions()).thenReturn(mockColumnDefinitions);
    target= new MyClass();
    Definition mockDef = Mockito.mock(Definition.class);
    List<Definition> defList = new ArrayList<Definition>();
    defList.add(mockDef);
    Iterator mockIterator = Mockito.mock(Iterator.class);
    Mockito.when(mockColumnDefinitions.iterator()).thenReturn(mockIterator);
    Mockito.when(mockIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, false);
    Mockito.when(mockIterator.next()).thenReturn(mockDef);
    Mockito.when(mockDef.getName()).thenReturn(NAME);
  }
 @Test
 public void testMyMethod() throws Exception {
    target.MyMethod();
 }
}
```

Test execution goes fine this place, and I have this type of code in different places, so it should work.
Inside the service I am testing I have following code:

```
ColumnDefinitions colDef = row.getColumnDefinitions();
Iterator<Definition> defIterator = colDef.iterator();
while (defIterator.hasNext()) {
    Definition def = defIterator.next();
    String columnName = def.getName();
}
```

When I debug this code, I see, that both `colDef` and `defIterator` are mocked successfully. I see something like that in debug variables area:

```
Mock for Iterator, hashCode: 430126690
```

But after `defIterator.next()` invocation I see that though `def` is an object and not null, it doesn't show hashcode like for `Iterator`, instead I see this:

```
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.
```

And after invoking this string:

```
String columnName = def.getName();
```

I immediately get `NullPointerException` like if def is null.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

EDIT 1 ________________________________________________________________________

I also tried to use `PowerMockito` with the same methods instead, the result is the same.

EDIT 2 ________________________________________________________________________

I added the whole test method code.

Comment: Can you copy paste the complete test method ?

Comment: @doanduyhai Please check, I added what's around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is been a while since this question was created. I have faced this same problem few days ago and I have solved it in the following manner (I hope my proposed solution helps someone in the future):

First of all, I want to clarify that `ColumnDefinition.Definition` class is a `public static` nested class that has four `private final` fields and only has one constructor: `Definition (String keyspace, String table, String name and DataType type)` (for more details please refer to the [ColumnDefinitions.Definition javadoc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.2/com/datastax/driver/core/ColumnDefinitions.Definition.html) and [ColumnDefinitions source code](https://github.com/tfredrich/cassandra-java-driver/blob/master/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/ColumnDefinitions.java)). Therefore this nested class could not be mocked by [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) nor [Powermock](http://powermock.github.io/) because of its `final` fields.

**SOLUTION:**

I had to create a real object, not a mocked one of the class `ColumnDefinition.Definition` using reflection, so you can initialise the `mockDef` object as follows:

```
Constructor<Definition> constructor = (Constructor<Definition>) Definition.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0]; // as Definition only has one constructor, 0 will be passed as index
constructor.setAccessible(true);
Definition mockDef = constructor.newInstance("keyspace", "table", "name", null);
```

replacing this line of code in your snippet:

```
Definition mockDef = Mockito.mock(Definition.class);
```

Then the NullPointerException will never be thrown again when executing this line of code:

```
String columnName = def.getName();
```